unable to redirect a after session expiration
I've created a listener that checks for user inactivity, the point of it is to log them out and send them to a default page with a message that they've been logged out. So far I'm trying to just send them to the default page, but im unable to do even that
the listener:


class SessionTimeoutListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $requestStack;
    private $csrfTokenManager;

    public function __construct(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => [
                ['onRequest', 100],
                ['refreshSessionCookie', 0],
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function refreshSessionCookie(ResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        if ($session->isStarted() && $event->getResponse()) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $cookieLifetime = 20;
            $lastUsed = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId(), time() + $cookieLifetime);
            $response->headers->setCookie($lastUsed);
        }
    }

        public function onRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        if (!$request->hasSession()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!$request->getSession()->has('_security_main')) {
            return;
        }
        if (!$request->cookies->has('accepted_cookies')) {
            return;
        }
        $session = $request->getSession();
        if (!$session->isStarted()) {
            return;
        }

        $lastUsedTimestamp = $session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed();
        $currentTime = time();
        $elapsedTime = $currentTime - $lastUsedTimestamp;
        $sessionTimeout = 20;

        if ($elapsedTime > $sessionTimeout) {
            $session->invalidate();
            $this->csrfTokenManager->refreshToken('security.csrf.token_manager');

            $logoutUrl = $request->getUriForPath('/cs/image-list');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($logoutUrl);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}

framework setting
 session:
        handler_id: 'session.handler.native_file'
        cookie_secure: true
        cookie_samesite: lax
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
        cookie_lifetime: 20
        gc_maxlifetime: 86400


services
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack: '@request_stack'

    App\EventListener\SessionTimeoutListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
        arguments:
            - '@security.csrf.token_manager'
            - '@request_stack'
    # Add the url_generator service definition as an alias for the router service
    session.handler.native_file:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler
        arguments: [ '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%' ]
    session:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
        public: true

I am using symfony 6.2
I have tried a method with url generator and do
$logoutUrl = $this->urlGenerator->generate('homepage_default', ['_locale' => 'cs']);
 $response = new RedirectResponse($logoutUrl);
 return $response->send();

$event->setResponse($response);
which did not work
What I'm expecting to happen is that when a user clicks on a button that normally sends the user to a different path, they will instead be signed out and sent to homepage_default if theyve been inactive long enough, I think thats what the code is supposed to do, but I am most likely missing something or dont understand some sort of function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
